# How to filter web3 events with date range?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, web3js, quorum

I have got some transactions which takes date as a parameter. When doing getPastEvents, is there any way to pass a date range in filter tab like below:

```
startDate: 10-03-2019
endDate: 30-03-2019
```

Comment: Are you looking for a solidity implementation or javascript implementation? Coz you can convert these dates into their timestamp (milliseconds since 1970 - Unix Time) then compare them as integers...

Comment: Transactions can not be filter in solidity. As Smart Contract can only change the current state.

Comment: @NahashonNjenga Can you please provide an example for a numeric range using web3JS?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why dates aren't reliable in a blockchain is that there is a lack of global clock.
It is one of the main topics in distributed computing.

Anyway back to your original question and how can you achieve it:
I'd suggest you to track blocks and it's timestamps and store it somewhere (db or even a file, your choice)
You can do that by using [getBlock](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getblock) function.

So you'll know your `fromBlock` & `toBlock` to query using [getPastEvents](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents)